# what is the pitch for vssop-8?

Tags: pcb, adc, surface-mount, reflow, stencil

I recently took on a personal project that requires a vssop-8 chip:ADC081C021. In order to help me solder the pins on the pcb, I ordered a vssop-8 stencil online. But when it arrived, I found the pitches were different.  The stencil is supposed to have a .5 mm pitch while the adc has a .65 mm pitch. Which one is correct? or is there no standard for vssop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to TI information where is a few types of vssop they have:DCU, DGS, DGK,DDU. ADC081C21 comes in DGK with pitch 0.65. https://www.ti.com/packaging/docs/searchtipackages.tsp?packageName=SO